# Data Importation Issue

Tags: relationships, data-import

Procedural question... I have a record set of individuals related to various organizations.   The employee/individual info set is handled well, EXCEPT FOR organization name... i can get work phone, work address, work city, work state, work zipcode.  And, in organization, there rightly are no individual information fields.

So, what comes first, chicken or the egg?

Assume it best practice to import organization info first, then the individual info???  As this makes sense.  But, I cannot find answer on how to get the "organization name/Employer" field into the individual recordset so I can then toggle the individual/organization relationship.

Hopefully, I'm missing something simple.

PS  I've imported 100k records for individuals so far, thou no employer/employee relationship.  Now the "vender" database set is coming on, thus another riddle.

thx

Answer (score 3):

In your spreadsheet, you should have the organization name and all organization info on the same row as the individual/employee info.

When mapping the import, for all the organization fields first select "employee of". another drop down menu will appear to select the field (org name, email...)

This will import both contacts with their relationship.
Note that you can only import 1 relationship per import.

Comment: I actually went through and imported all my organizations first, with all their info (email, phone, address, etc). Then I imported my individuals and did what you said with selecting the employee of and then the org name.

Answer (score 1):

Jenni Simmonis's clarification is precisely correct.   Import organizations first.  PRIOR TO importing "employees", be certain the relationship desired exists. Then, when importing "employees", include the organization and that field then select the relationship "employee of".  Works perfectly!   Thx.